# Removing Children in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

My flash game exists of a timeline with multiple frames (I know I should avoid the timeline)
The point of the game is a point and click adventure. The object that you are able to pick up get spawned and destroyed accordingly as you enter and leave the room. now my problem is when entering frame 14 (accessibel from frame 12) it creates a piece of paper which you are able to pick up if you have another item. Now my problem is when you can't or don't pick up the paper and go back to frame 12 (only exit is to frame 12), you can't click on any other object and you are basicly stuck on frame 12. When leaving and entering other rooms it works properly but for some reason it doesn't for on the paper on frame 14.

My code to remove objects works as following

In my Main.as Documentclass I have a function that called as soon as the game starts which does the following

```
if (lastframe == 14)
{
    trace (prop.numChildren);
    while (prop.numChildren )
    {
        prop.removeChildAt(0);
    }
}
```

The lastframe variable is established when moving from frames
this function is found on the frame itself (each exit function on it's own respective frame)

```
function exitKantine(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Main.lastframe = 14;
    gotoAndStop(12);
}
```

The function to remove the prop actually removes it but then causes all other clickable objects to be unusable.

Thanks for looking at my question and thanks in advance for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say instead of removing children, add it once in the beginning, add all the listeners in the beginning, and toggle the visibility instead of trying to addChild and removeChild every time you want to hide it. Use an array so you can have a few happening at the same time.

something like this:

private function init():void

```
{

assignVars();
addListeners();

  stage.addChild   // make sure this is in document class or you are passing stage to the class using it


}


for (var i = 0; i < _thingsAry.length; i++)
{

if (_thingsAry[i] == 14)
{
    _thingsAry[i].visible = false;
    trace("the visibility of _thingsAry[" + i + "] is " + _thingsAry[i].visible
}
}
```